# Scikitlearn (textual) CountVectorizer (csr_matrix) to dictionary?

Tags: python, nlp, countvectorizer

I used scikit-learn CountVectorizer function to count word frequency in raw text, and it seems to be working when printed, but i can't find how to convert it to a dictionary or an array i could work with.

I tried .toarray() but this only returns the values, not the word position associated with it.

```
bowChapters = []
for i in range(0,27):
    countV = CountVectorizer(max_features=50) #top 50 words for the chapter 
    chapter = [temp2[i]]
    bowChapters.append(countV.fit_transform(chapter))

print(bowChapters[0]) #Prints correctly in console
```

the output of print is :

```
 (0, 29)       11
 (0, 35)       29
 (0, 22)       12
 (0, 18)       8
```

I'd like to get a dictionary where i can see the tuples assiciated with values but couldn't find the right function in the doc

Comment: Is `CountVectorizer.get_feature_names()` what you are looking for? [This method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.get_feature_names) maps from the integer indices to the feature names.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem, glad this helped!